# Complete working of AngularJs $watch?

Tags: angularjs

I was learning it through [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on) for `$watch` in `AngularJs`. how does `$scope` and `$digest` linked for watching the Expression.